# Stylesheet won't load even when linked

Tags: wp-query, jquery, css

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I created a page with accordians, the jquery script loads just fine but when I link the CSS stylesheet, no CSS shows up. It is not an external stylesheet, I posted the CSS in the same stylesheet used for all pages which is styles.css

The page

http://scarincihollenbeck.com/law-practices/

When it's inspected the stylesheet says it loaded but It doesn't display anything. Been stuck for hours, any help would be appreciated.

```
*:before,
*:after {
 -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

 .container-lawpractice {
  width: 90%;
  margin: -10px auto;
}

 .container-lawpractice > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

 .dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
   color: white;
   background: #d02422;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1a1a1a inset, 0 -1px 0 black inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1a1a1a inset, 0 -1px 0 black inset;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1a1a1a inset, 0 -1px 0 black inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 17px;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  font-family: 'DIN1451W01-Mittelschrif', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
 }

  .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
   background: #121211;
   color: white;
   border-left: 10px solid #d02422;
  }

  .dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  }

  .dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
   transition: transform 0.6s;
  }

  .dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
 }

 .dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
  content: '\25BC';
  }

  .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  }

 .dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
  }

  .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
   background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   padding: 10px 10px;
   font-size: 13px;
   text-indent: 30px;
   font-family: 'DIN1451W01-Mittelschrif', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   border-left: 10px solid #d02422;
   font-weight: 500;
  }

  .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #d02422;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  }

  .dropdown .show,
  .dropdown .hide {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  }

.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

.whole-body {
    position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full-body {
    position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}



.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5% 0% 0 0;
}

.box-hover{
  display: none;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: rgb(208, 36, 34);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15% 0 0 15%;
  padding: 5%;

}





@media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .col-sm-6{width:80%;}

  .container{width:80%;}
```

I'm also running a bootstrap script if that's any importance. Been stuck for hours, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the CSS to your child themes style.css file or load it using wp_enqueue_scripts

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsites_load_custom_styles' );
function wpsites_load_custom_styles() {

    wp_register_style( 'custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css' );

}
```

[Source](http://wpsites.net/wordpress-themes/second-style-sheet-theme/)

Answer (score -1):

You could add to your functions.php (in child theme) a reference to just that one page (is_page('law-practices')) and enqueue just for that one page:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'law_practice_enqueue_style' );
function law_practice_enqueue_style(){
   if (is_page('law-practices')){
     wp_register_style( 'law-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . 'law-style.css', false );
     wp_enqueue_style('law-style');
     }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this instead. Replace your css by : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/stylesheets/styles.css" />` in the head section

Comment: Will this solve the issue?